# What is this strange SELinux attribute on several of my files?

Tags: arch-linux, fedora, permissions, selinux, xattr

I have run `exa --long --extended` on a folder containing some wallpapers and I noticed that it returns a strange `security.selinux (len 37)` tag on several of my files. I'd like to know what it is and how to get rid of it. I assume it's something that got passed when I backed up my files from my old Fedora install, but I've since moved from Fedora to Arch and I have switched to `apparmor` due to the better support for it on latter.

Here is what I'm talking about:

```
drwxrwxr-x@  - MYUSER 29 juni  19:09 wallhaven_wallhaven_cc_search_q_yosemite_categories_100_purity_110_atleast_2560x1440_sorting_relevance_order_desc
                                   └── security.selinux (len 37)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. If anyone experiences the same, you can run

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type d,f -exec setfattr -x security.selinux {} \;
```

Comment: The `setattr -x security.selinux` command indeed effectively strips all SELinux extended file attributes. This should never be done like that, unless - like in your case - you don't need to access these files on that other SELinux based system any more. As you said, these attributes are very likely a leftover from your previous SELinux-based system. You should accept your own answer :-)

Comment: @Edward Yeah, I just can't accept it yet - I have to wait 24h ;) `setfacl -bR <file or dir>` did *not* work, so I'm guessing that SELinux does not set any ACL policies?

Comment: Correct, SELinux does not set ACLs. For some filesystems, ACLs are in fact, just like SELinux labels, defined through extended file attributes, but in another namespace. `setfacl` makes changes to those ACLs by modifying the extended attributes.